# Click Item in ListView React-Native not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react-native and I want to press to to specific item in ListView, but when I click the item which I want to select I didn't get a console log message and I didn't get any errors so my code look like this:

in renderRow my code look like this:

```
renderRow(record) {
    return (
            <View style={styles.row}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow()}>
                    <View style={styles.info}>
                        <Text style={styles.items}>{record.nom}</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
}
```

and _pressRow function simple console log:

```
 _pressRow (rowID: number) {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
```

and render function:

```
 render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView scrollsToTop={false} style={styles.menu}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this.renderRow}
                />
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
```

How can I resolve this issue and thanks.

Comment: I think you have to bind that function in the constructor of the component:
`this._ pressRow = this._ pressRow.bind(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the [autobind-decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator)? Using your code as is the _pressRow method won't be triggered. When I add the autobind decorator or change _pressRow into a fat-arrow function the console.log does work for me:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableHighlight, Text, ScrollView, ListView } from 'react-native'

_pressRow = (rowID: number) => {
  console.log("clicked")
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
    })

    this.state = {
      dataSource: this.dataSource.cloneWithRows([
        { nom: 'a' },
        { nom: 'b' },
      ]),
    }
  }

  renderRow(record) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._pressRow()}>
          <View>
            <Text>{record.nom}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView scrollsToTop={false}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `this._pressRow()` to `this._pressRow.bind(this)` if your function is in your Class

Answer (score 0):

I used `TouchableHighlight` to wrap "un-pressable" component (accompany with changing `this._pressRow` to `this._pressRow.bind(this)`).

Moreover, some component (such as Text component) does not fill all the space of `ListView` row. So that `onPress` only works if you press right at text (it does not work if you press on the row location that does not have any text). So that it is useful to wrap with `TouchableHighlight` component.